# How do I count the occurrences of each word in a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to figure out how to count the occurrences of each word in a string entered by the user. I want to use an array for the input and copy each element/word into another array(words), only if the word hasn't been copied already. If it's already been copied, I want to just increment the number of occurrences by using a parallel counter array(count). So far, what I have compiles, but when I run the program it just gives me 0 for all of the count values, and it still prints every word in the string even if it's already been printed before. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 1000
int read_line(char *str, int n);

int main() {
    char input[STR_LEN + 1];
    char *token;
    char words[50];
    char *p1;
    char *p2;
    int i;
    int count[50] = { 1 };

    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    read_line(input, STR_LEN);   //Calls the readline function

    printf("Input: %s\n", input);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        p1 = &input[i];
        p2 = &words[i];
        if (strstr(p1, input) == 0) {
            strcpy(p2, p1);
        } else
            count[i]++;     
    }
    printf("Output: \n");
    token = strtok(words, " ,.!");  //tokenizes the first word in the string

    while (token != NULL) {    
        printf("%s\t\t%d\n", token, count[i]);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ,.!");  //tokenizes subsequent words in the string
    } 
    return 0;
}

int read_line(char *s1, int n) {
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (i < n) {
            *s1++ = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *s1 = '\0';  //terminates string
    return i;    //number of characters stored
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array of strings instead of an array of characters for `words`:

```
char *words[50];
```

You should allocate copies of the words with `strdup()`.

You main loop is inconsistent, you are not matching words, you lookup string fragments for each offset into the string.  Move the tokenization code to the loop and match strings, not characters.